# How to copy audio stream using FFMpeg API ( not a command line tool )

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I'm developing some Video Editing Apps on Android.

the objective of the app is "Editing Videos on Android".

and...

I'm just completed making video file using some images.
but.. I can't attach audio into the video.

### my method is same as follows.

1.VideoStream, audio stream creation using AVFormatContext

2.Movie encoding in video stream was successful

3.Encode codec open in audio stream was successful

4.Set sample format to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP

5.Sample rate and channel was set same as source audio

6.Choose appropriate Decoder and read packet

7.Convert packets using swr_converter, setting same as sample format

8.Encode converted data

9.memory deallocation

10.END!

---

### Problem is here:

Video of finally created video file was normally played. but the Audio wasn't.

It heared like weird. It have many noises and plays slowly.

I've googled with many keywords but they only say about "FFmpeg command line usage".

I wanna make with FFMpeg API. not a Command line tool.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague without some kind of code to go along with it, as trust me there are a lot of things that can go wrong when using ffmpeg's libraries directly (and on Windows there is no debuging). Unfortunately ffmpeg's libraries are not well documented so it is generally best to read the source code for ffmpeg in order to use its libraries. Find the equivalent command line options to perform what you want and track that through ffmpeg's source to see the library calls.